# Create a href link for 'each hashtags' from JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, replace

Create a href link for 'each hashtags'.

However the code below only create href link only for the 'last hashtag' in the JSON file.

Iterate through JSON array

```
rows
[ ], [ ], 
[ 
    content: "With the #a b, c at tonight's ..",
    hashtags: [
     "a",
     "b",
     "c" 
],

$.ajax('https://rest.xyz.com/..', {
  type: 'GET', 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function( data ) { 
    for(i in data.rows[3].hashtags){
      content3 = data.rows[3].content.replace(
        new RegExp('#'+data.rows[3].hashtags[i], 'g'), 
        '<a href="https://x.com/hashtags/'+      
        data.rows[3].hashtags[i]+'"'+
        'target="_blank">'+'#'+data.rows[3].hashtags[i]+'</a>'
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for map! Map takes a function that transforms an element, and applies that function to each element in an array. It gives you back a new array with all of the new values. I would map over the hashtags array and return a new array containing the markup. Then you can insert them into the dom!

```
$.ajax('https://rest.xyz.com/..', {
  type: 'GET', 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function( data ) {
    data.rows[3].hashtags.map(function(hashtag) {
      return '<a href="https://x.com/hashtags/' +
             hashtag +
             'target="_blank">#' +
             hashtag +
             '</a>';
    })
    .forEach(function(link) {
      // Do stuff here with each one!
      // $('body').append(link);
    });
  }
});
```

Of course, you can skip the map, and just forEach over each link, creating the tag and inserting it right away. For readability, I have them in two separate steps.

Comment: How do I replace the hashtags in the string with the matching mapped hashtags

Comment: How to replace the whole content: "With the #a, #b at tonight's  #c.." with the matching mapped hashtags.With the <a href="..">#a</a>, <a href="..">#b</a> at tonight's  <a href="..">#c</a>